# Redux expects listener to be function

Tags: javascript, redux

Hello I'm using redux and i am running against this problem.
I am adding a listener function to the built in subscribe method from redux.

```
store.subscribe(historyManager(store.getState()));
```

I pass the state to this listener.

The listener itself looks like this:

```
const historyManager = function (state) {
    // if(['channel', 'account', 'tab', 'main', 'ui.sub'].indexOf(changedVal)) return pushState();
    // 'ui.piet' // wek
    // 'ui.piet.klaas.jan' // niet
    // if(['set', 'in', 'url'].indexOf(changedVal)) return replaceState();
    // doe geen zak

    console.log(state)

};
```

Ignore the comments, for now i am simply worried about logging the state that i pass from the subscribe.

In my console I get the error :

```
redux.js:138 Uncaught Error: Expected the listener to be a function.
```

Could it be because my function has no return statement?

Comment: just `store.subscribe(historyManager)`

Comment: @Federkun how would i pass the state to my listener function then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking `historyManager` directly when you call `store.subscribe`. That way you are passing `undefined` to `store.subscribe`, instead of a callback.

What you want to do is to just pass the function to the subscribe method.

```
store.subscribe(historyManager)
```

then redux itself will invoke `historyManager`. You can get the current state by calling `store.getState()` from the `historyManager`

```
const store = ...
const historyManager = function () {
    const state = store.getState()
};

store.subscribe(historyManager);
```